# How do I make parallel async HTTP requests using httpx (versus aiohttp) in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

### This was based on a typo, and simple mistake.

Not deleting since it has sample code for httpx.

I'm attempting to leverage `asyncio` to parallelize several long-ish running web requests. Because I'm migrating from the `requests` library, I would like to use the `httpx` library, due to the similar API. My environment is a Python 3.7.7 Anaconda distribution with all required packages installed (Windows 10).

However, despite being able to use `httpx` for synchronous web requests (or for serially executing async requests that run one after another), I have not been able to succeed at running more than one async request at a time, despite easily doing so with the `aiohttp` library.

Here's example code that runs cleanly in `aiohttp`: (Note that I'm running in Jupyter, so I already have an event loop, thus the lack of `asyncio.run()`.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
import httpx

async def call_url(session):
    url = "https://services.cancerimagingarchive.net/services/v3/TCIA/query/getCollectionValues"        
    response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
    #response.raise_for_status() 
    return response

for i in range(1,5):
    start = time.time() # start time for timing event
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: #use aiohttp
    #async with httpx.AsyncClient as session:  #use httpx
        await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
    print(f'{i} call(s) in {time.time() - start} seconds')
```

This results in an expected response time profile:

```
1 call(s) in 7.9129478931427 seconds
2 call(s) in 8.876991510391235 seconds
3 call(s) in 9.730034589767456 seconds
4 call(s) in 10.630006313323975 seconds
```

However, if I uncomment `async with httpx.AsyncClient as session:  #use httpx`  and comment out `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: #use aiohttp` (to swap in `httpx` for `aiohttp`) then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-25244245165a> in async-def-wrapper()
     17         await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
     18     print(f'{i} call(s) in {time.time() - start} seconds')

AttributeError: __aexit__
```

In my research online, I could only find this one Medium article by Simon Hawe showing how to use `httpx` for parallel request. See https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-boost-your-python-apps-using-httpx-and-asynchronous-calls-9cfe6f63d6ad

However, the example async code doesn't even use an async session object so I was a bit suspicious just to start. The code does not execute in either a Python 3.7.7 environment or in Jupyter. (Code is here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Shawe82/a218066975f4b325e026337806f8c781/raw/3cb492e971c13e76a07d1a1e77b48de94aa7229c/concurrent_download.py)

It results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\async_http_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run(download_all_photos('100_photos'))
  File "C:\Users\stborg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fastai2\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\stborg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fastai2\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File ".\async_http_test.py", line 16, in download_all_photos
    resp = await httpx.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
TypeError: object Response can't be used in 'await' expression
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong, as `httpx` is built for async. I'm just not sure what it is!

Comment: Future readers might find working examples at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) (under **Important Note** section) as well.

Answer (score 13):

OK. This is frankly embarrassing. There is no need for a workaround. In the problem statement I completely neglected to call the AsyncClient constructor...  I cannot believe I missed that for so long.  Oh, my...

To fix, simply add the missing parenthesis to the AsyncClient constructor:

```
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as session:  #use httpx
        await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
```

Answer (score 6):

While experimenting further in writing this question, I discovered a subtle difference in the way `httpx` and `aiohttp` treat context managers.

In the code that introduces the question, the following code worked with `aiohttp`:

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: #use aiohttp
        await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
```

This code passes the ClientSession context as a paramater to the `call_url` method. I assume that after `asyncio.gather()` completes, then resources are cleaned up as per the normal `with` statement.

However, the same approach with `httpx` fails, as above.  This can be easily fixed, however, by simply avoiding the `with` statement altogether, and manually closing the `AsyncClient`.

In other words, replace

```py
    async with httpx.AsyncClient as session:  #use httpx
        await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
```

with

```
    session = httpx.AsyncClient() #use httpx
    await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
    await session.aclose()
```

to fix the issue.

Here's the working code in its entirety:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
import httpx

async def call_url(session):
    url = "https://services.cancerimagingarchive.net/services/v3/TCIA/query/getCollectionValues"
    response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
    return response

for i in range(1,5):
    start = time.time() # start time for timing event
    #async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: #use aiohttp
    session = httpx.AsyncClient() #use httpx
    await asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
    await session.aclose()
    print(f'{i} call(s) in {time.time() - start} seconds')
```

Comment: Why do u import `aiohttp` in the last code example?

Comment: Your final code returns `SyntaxError`. It should be like this:

`
for i in range(1,5):
    start = time.time() # start time for timing event
    session = httpx.AsyncClient() #use httpx
    asyncio.gather(*[call_url(session) for x in range(i)])
    print(f'{i} call(s) in {time.time() - start} seconds')
`