# httpx - send multiple requests from dynamic list

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, request, python-asyncio

I would like to send multiple request at once to the API. But I do not know how to trigger the requests because part of the URL is loaded from dynamic list which can have different length every time.

Right now I am looping through the list and sending the request one by one but that is kinda slow.

```
for url_param in parameters:
    r = httpx.get(f"http://my-api/{url_param}")
```

Is there any way to trigger all the requests at once with httpx and asyncio?

Comment: use async requests https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests

Comment: I know I have to use async requests, but how I can do it with the dynamic list?

Comment: with `asyncio.gather` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61537571/202168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load all the request in an array and send them together in an async client session

```
import asyncio
import httpx

async def do_tasks():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = [client.get(f"http://my-api/{url_param}") for url_param in parameters]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```